# Google adsense in android apps

Tags: android, google-play, ads, adsense

I am trying to enable google ads in my android app, before posting it to google play, but, On google adsense account, it asks me to enter url of my site, so I have to post ads on site. Is there any way to enable those ads in app? And since I have never had any experience with html or php, I can not make a website with ads... What are your suggestion? How can I earn some money publishing my app? Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like their upgrading the stuff today! I have not used it, but tried googling it :)

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/1307264?hl=en-GB

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try `admob.com` instead. It is the ads platform on mobile app.